# Remove the auto download of a URL that points to a google bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have files stored on google cloud storage. Google provides me a URL to access this files, but when I access this URL the file is auto downloaded. I wish to know if it is possible to remove or don't allow this auto download when we access the file URL. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The download feature is handled by the client.

Calling the URL for an object stored in a bucket will return the object in the body of the [HTTP request](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), and the client will choose what to do with this data.

If you use a web browser, the choice of downloading or not a file is usually given by the header [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). In general, there are some [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) that will be displayed on the browser itself (according to [Chrome help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759), videos, images, PDFs and web pages will be displayed directly on the browser), while others will download directly.

To modify the MIME type of the files stored in a bucket, you must change it's [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type), so the browser will behave in the way you want.