# Prevent Files from Being Downloaded in google cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have video upload project on laravel. I have uploaded the laravel project on the google cloud by creating VM in compute engine. Everything i working. There is a security issue.

Like the video is getting uploaded using storage link. When any video is getting uploaded then a public url is getting saved into table.

The url is like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/Videos_Published/Earth_Science/659d4fd65bc53_cropped.mp4
```

This should be play on the player. But it must not be download from any where. How can I prevent the video using google cloud?
Should I store anywhere else on the google cloud.
Please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: It's a difficult use case. Are you sure that you can't save the video played on Youtube or Netflix? No, you can't! If the data land on the user computer, the data are "lost". Sure, you can have layers that increase the difficulty to save locally the video, but to prevent it is utopia. Does the effort worth?

Comment: Thankyou for reply.
But how can I make more secure the videos like netflix or amazon prime videos?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue? What are you trying to do and How are you configuring it? Are you facing issues with Cloud storage security?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni, the laravel project is deployed on the google cloud server. Everything is working fine. On the website, there are videos, which are being played into the html player. Thats ok. But if I right click and copy the video url fron the inspect element and then if I paste the url on the browser. Then the video is being download. I want to prevent download the videos. May be it's not 100%. But I want to add functionality to prevent the videos by download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting [content-disposition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects) to 'inline' will fix the automatic download issue.

Unfortunately there is no bucket-level inherited setting for this, you will need to set it on every object and keep setting it when you create new objects.

That being said, this is completely reliant on the browser doing the right thing. Even then all the user has to do is click 'File -> Save Page As'.

For more details check this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841527/18265702) by Jofre.

**Update:**

Along with the above suggestions, alternatively you can choose [`media encryption with DRM`](https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/2022/02/drm-content-protection/) to prevent files from auto download in Google cloud.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. Can I use blob url? Will it be useful to prevent the videos?

Comment: Yes, The Blob URL will prevent the auto download. But as per this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62125040/18265702) they can still save it, feeding the HTML element with a blob:// URL doesn't prevent any "save As" actions.

Comment: Then I can use media encryption with DRM. I think.

Comment: @Vinod Might be, Check this [Link](https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/2022/02/drm-content-protection/) once about DRM.

Comment: Thnx for your help. I think DRM can solve the issue.

Comment: @Vinod 

No mention. I have updated my answer now for better visibility. Have a look.